# when  click itself  why it doesn't hide in jquery?

Tags: jquery

html structure:

```
<div id="tabswitch">
    <ul>
        <li class="tab1">Tab 1</li>
        <li class="tab2">Tab 2</li>
        <li class="tab3">Tab 3</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-container tab1">
        <p>venenatis dolor nec feugiat. Nam id tincidunt augue. Nam eleifend scelerisque bibendum. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-container tab2">
        <img src="http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/51495/51495,1232158237,2/stock-photo-cute-chocolate-lab-puppy-23407567.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="tab-container tab3">
        <iframe src ="http://google.com" width="100%" height="300">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#tabswitch ul li:first").addClass("active");
        jQuery("#tabswitch div.tab-container:first").show();

        jQuery("#tabswitch ul li").click(function(){
            jQuery("#tabswitch div.tab-container").hide();
            jQuery("#tabswitch ul li").removeClass("active");

   })
    });
```

for the default state. the tab1 is show, but why when i click the tab1. it doesn't hide? namely, why this line doesn't effect on it?   `jQuery("#tabswitch div.tab-container").hide();`

the tab1 content matches the  `#tabswitch div.tab-container`

Comment: you want to hide `<li class="tab1">Tab 1</li>..if yes then ..you have not written the code to hide this..that's y it's not hiding :)
`

Comment: it's working here- http://jsfiddle.net/Newuser123/fVPeA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your CSS specify that .tab1 or .tab-container has a display property other than none?

I think that it may hide the element (using display:none) when the click event is triggered, but it immediately gets a CSS display property of something else (like "block") when you remove the "active" class.  Try putting the `removeClass("active")` before the `hide()`.

Are you re-inventing the wheel here?  Is jQuery-UI's tabs what you're trying to create?:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: you are right. in the css style., there is a style as this:.tab-container{display:none;}. i only wnat to know why when i click the tab1. it doesn't hide? namely, why this line doesn't effect on it? jQuery("#tabswitch div.tab-container").hide();

Comment: My guess above is that it _is_ hiding the tab when you click on it, but that it is immediately shown again when, on the next line, you remove the "active" class.  The result is that it doesn't actually hide at all because the changes happen too quickly.  In your CSS, have you set a display property for either the tab-container or tab1 **that is _not_ none**?  If not, then my guess above is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide the current tab you ca n use this...

```
jQuery("#tabswitch ul li").click(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            jQuery("#tabswitch div.tab-container").hide();
            jQuery("#tabswitch ul li").removeClass("active");

   });
```

you are also missing `;` at the end of your click handler..

you want [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Newuser123/84Ydd/), i think..

Comment: i don't want to hide the tab1. only to know why when i click the li. the div.tab-container doesn't hide. but there is a line in the click function. jQuery("#tabswitch div.tab-container").hide();